# How to get project or root dir in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, solarium

I use Symfony 5 and Solarium. I want to get the project dir (or root dir) in my Controller (extends from AbstractController).

I saw some anwers with kernel, creating new services, etc..

But, isn't it just a function that call the project dir without creating some custom services etc..?

Thanks !

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't need any service for this. You can get from container in your controller.

`$this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');`

Other way is bind it on yaml.

```
    _defaults:
        bind:
            # pass this value to any $projectDir argument for any service
            # that's created in this file (including controller arguments)
            string $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

So you can inject each service and controller as **$projectDir**.

```
public class YourController {
   public function index(string $projectDir){
        // Your code
   }
}
```

```
public class YourService {
   public function __construct(string $projectDir){
        // Your code
   }
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#accessing-configuration-parameters

Answer (score 11):

Since Symfony 6.1 you can autowire parameters
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-1-service-autowiring-attributes

```php
<?php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\Autowire;

class MyService
{
    public function __construct(
        #[Autowire('%kernel.project_dir%/config/dir')]
        private $dir,
    ) {}
}
```